# iPhone Facebook Dialog Feed not displaying Post to Wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

I am using [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

If user is not logged in, the Facebook login dialog will be displayed.  Once logged in, it goes to the Facebook Mobile page (Profile, Messages, More).  How can I have it go to the Post to Your Wall page?

Thanks!